# How to get a while loop to work in a nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, nested

For my code, I made a nested loop so that there will be string combinations of colours and numbers inserted below.

One more thing I wanted to add to my code is for the same place in the colours to not match with the same place for the numbers. I tried doing this with a while loop so that the code will not align colours and numbers with the same place in the length but my code will not work or print out repeated outputs.

I would like for my code when put in ["grey","black","white"] for colours and [1,2,3] as numbs, it will print out:

grey, 2
grey, 3
black, 1
black, 3
white, 1
white, 2

```
def all_combinations(colours,numbs):

#converts numbers in list into strings
    numbs =''.join(map(str, numbs))

    for colour in colours:
        for numb in numbs:
            #while len(colours) != len(numbs):
            print(colour +", "+ numb )
            
            
all_combinations(["grey","black","white"],[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Have a look at `enumerate()`. It returns the item as well as its index. Then you can skip when the 2 indexes are the same.

Comment: Your `while` condition makes no sense. Since neither `colours` nor `numbs` change within the loop, `len(colours) != len(numbs)` will always return the same value, meaning that the `while` loop either is infinite, if `colours` and `numbs` have different lengths, or does nothing at all, if `colours` and `numbs` have the same length.